# Resolving the ambiguity of the word "assez"?

Tags: vocabulaire

As I walked into the library just now, I thought to myself "It's quite cold in here". The closest translation I could think of was:

> Cette bibliothèque est assez froide.

It seems, to my French-as-Second-Language understanding, that this sentence has somewhat opposite possible meanings, considering that I need places that are quite warm in order for me to study well. That is, this sentence could mean "This library is quite cold [and I'm noticing this because I don't like it]", or "This library is cold enough [for my needs, because I require cold temperatures]".

It seems that context gives no clue to which meaning this sentence has.

Questions:

1. Is the word "assez" in this sentence equally ambiguous, or is it more likely to mean one of the two meanings more often than the other (ie, between "enough" and "quite")?
2. In general, does "assez" more often tend to mean one of the two meanings more than the other?
3. If I wanted to use other words to clarify my meaning (ie, to emphasize "enough", or to emphasize "quite"), what words could I use?

Comment: Since nobody mentioned this, I learned "assez" to mean "rather", so I would translate your sentence as "the library is rather cold".

Comment: Same thing happens in Spanish, “bastante fría” is literally “cold enough” but idiomatically “rather cold”..

Comment: At a gathering after graduating from high school a friend who was in French with me played a song and I, having just learned the usage, said, "C'est *assez* bonne !" She might have been familiar with more than the literal definition at the time, but to this day I'm not quite sure if she knew it was the compliment I meant it to be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't say "Ce bibliothèque est assez froid" but "Il fait assez froid dans la bibliothèque"

"assez" means both "quite" and "enough"

Q1 : The word "assez" in this sentence is clear, it clearly means "quite"

If you want to say "It is cold enough in the library you should say "Il fait **suffisamment** froid dans la bibliothèque"

Q2: "assez" means most of time "quite", when "assez" is at the end of a sentence, it means "enough". But sometimes it can be both "quite" and "enough", I don't really know how to tell you, but if you don't know, use "assez" for "quite" and "suffisamment" for "enough"

Q3 : So if you want to say "quite", use the word "assez", if you want to say "enough", use "suffisament"

-Native French speaker ;)

Comment: Can you give me an example of a sentence where "assez" is at the end of the sentence?

Comment: "J'en ai mangé assez" - "I've eaten enough of it"

Comment: "Ce n'est pas assez" - "This is not enough"

Comment: Avec nos 2 réponses je pense qu’on a une réponse complète... "plutôt" pour "quite", "suffisament" pour "enough"...

Comment: Oui je suis d'accord. Par contre je trouve ça bizarre le "Cette bibliothèque est assez froide.". On dit comme ça en Belgique ? Parce qu'en France on dit pas ça, on dit "Il fait assez froid dans la bibliothèque".

Comment: J’ai failli ajouter un point là-dessus mais on s’éloignait trop de l’objet de la question. Effectivement "il fait froid ici" me semble plus idiomatique. D’une manière plus générale, il fait froid dans les lieux, mais les objets, les personnes, etc sont froids (ou chauds d’ailleurs hein, on a dans le coeur le soleil qu’on n’a pas dehors comme dirait l’autre :-))

Comment: I disagree with Q1 answer being obvious. It could perfectly mean “enough” with the right context. Speaker could have been looking for a cold room to store some item temporarily (say, some food or beverage), and say that when he enters the study. Kind of what Laurent says in his answer below :)

Comment: @spectras actually I agree with Antoine on this part... "Obvious" is maybe too strong, but "most reasonable" it it, definitely. Indeed without a context I would not expect someone to go into a libary especially for the "cool" aspect of it... On the opposite, if talking about a fridge, I would think that "enough" is the most reasonable meaning...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me correct your sentence. "Bibliothèque" being a feminine word, the sentence should be

> Cette bibliothèque est assez froide.

Then to answer your question, you’re right this could be ambiguous without context, but in many occasions you will have a context, so that shouldn’t be an issue. Without one you can only assume. In this case I would say logic will be your best friend... A library is not necessarily something you expect to be cold, it would then be more reasonable to think someone says this thinking "quite" cold.

If you were to use other words, I would say that "plutôt" would really be the best translation for "quite". I’m trying to think about English sentences where it cannot replace "quite" and have a hard time finding one, but maybe this is because of my own limitations in English...

On the other hand I have more difficulty replacing "assez" without using a superlative, as it is actually a very precise translation of "enough".
EDIT: I don’t know why I didn’t think of it before, but as pointed by Antoine in his answer, "suffisamment" would be in many (I won’t dare to say all) cases an appropriate substitute for "assez" when meaning "enough".

Comment: Actually, most places (libraries, restaurants, offices spaces) I expect to be quite cold -- at least, that's how they often feel to *me*! So if I understand you correctly, "Cette bibliothèque est assez froide" really is in fact ambiguous? What do you think of a the other answer to this question, that says that if in doubt, "assez" probably means "quite", instead of "enough"?

Comment: I don’t really agree with it but have no reference at hand. We both agree though that in this sentence the most reasonable meaning is "quite". And I agree indeed for the "end of sentence" meaning "enough". In doubt, as I said the logic will help you decide, but not everybody has the same logic :-)

Comment: Oui tout à fait, d’où mon commentaire sur l’autre réponse... devrais-je éditer ?

Comment: @silph I would say that cold not being something one usually look for in a library, the first interpretation would indeed be that it is a bit too cold for comfort. Now if someone is looking at cold being a desirable feature of a library, for whatever reason *(let's say for instance that cold improves the preservation of archived documents)*, then yes, it can be interpreted as *adequately cold*.

Comment: @Feelew: I might happily say, when entering a library, "Ah, it's quite warm in here!", "Il fait assez chaud!". (And additionally, there *are* people who enjoy cold working spaces). So if I understand you correctly, the sentence really is ambiguous (given that "Il fait assez froid" might mean "quite" and "Il fait assez chaud!" might mean "enough")?

Comment: @silph Well! Let’s say you do look forward to the air conditioning of the library and we walk along on our way there. Then you may or may not mention the fact you can’t wait to escape the heat, but I should be able to hear from the way you say the sentence, as we enter the library, whether you are enjoying the cold *(then it is cold enough for your liking)* or feel nervous about it *(then it is too cold for you)*. If it is written, then chances are there is a context surrounding the sentence, which should explain how to interpret it. But on its own, yes it could be ambiguous.

Comment: Though people would usually interpret it as I mentioned previously (I believe).

Comment: @Feelew you made this very clear; thanks;

Answer (score 2):

While everything that's been said in the other answers also applies to Belgian French, there exists an extra way to disambiguate the two meaning of *assez* in that dialect: **word order**.

> Il fait assez froid = Il fait plutôt froid = It is rather cold
>
> Il fait froid assez = Il fait suffisamment froid = It is cold enough

This practice of putting *assez* after the adjective it qualifies used to be common to all dialects of French, but this went out of usage outside Belgium.